# Where can I find Maui controls' default DataTemplates?

Tags: xaml, .net-core, maui

I want to look at the default DataTemplate for the control `MenuItem` in Maui. Maui's documentation [shows the default template for FlyoutItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#default-template-for-flyoutitems) and I'm sure the two are very similar, but I would like to look at the MenuItem's template as well. I want to take that template and then tweak it to make the control look somewhat different in my own application but still following some of the same rules as the default control. I know I can simply just supply a DataTemplate of my own without looking at the original, but I still want to reproduce some of the design elements of the original template.

I went into [Maui's source code for the `MenuItem` class](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Menu/MenuItem.cs), but there's no indication here as to where I can find the default DataTemplate. I searched through a lot of things in the repo with the name MenuItem, but to no avail.

Where can I find the default DataTemplate for individual Maui controls in general?

EDIT: Now that I have looked closer, I see that the documentation showing the default FlyoutItem template says you can use it for MenuItem as well. So I will try that. Still, is there a way to find controls' default data templates in the repository? Or is it better to just use the ones presented in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [Default template for FlyoutItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#default-template-for-flyoutitems):

> The same template can also be used for
> [MenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.menuitem)
> objects.

Furthermore, a [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.datatemplate) is used to specify the appearance of data, and typically uses data binding to display data. A common usage scenario for data templates is when displaying data from a collection of objects in a control such as a [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.collectionview),  [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.listview?view=net-maui-8.0), [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.carouselview) and [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shell?view=net-maui-8.0). So you may just simply use those controls' default [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.datatemplate) presented in the official documentation.